# Get desired output in textbox from serial port scale

Tags: c#, .net

i have develop application for getting weight from weigh Bridge machine using C#.Net. i am trying lot of ways but, doesn't read correct data format weight from weigh bridge machine. i am getting output like

> 00000001Kg00000001B00000001B00000001B00000001B00000001B00000001B00000001B

continuously get from serial port.i want to get weight from weigh bridge machine my code is listed below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames(); 
        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);              
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;      
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        if (_serialPort != null)
            _serialPort.Dispose();

        _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;
        _serialPort.Open();
        textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";        
    }
    private delegate void Closure();
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));
        else
        {
            int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
            int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
            if (nbrDataRead == 0)
                return;
            string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            textBox1.Text += str.ToString();
        }
     }
```

how could i get right weight for save it into my database? in Order to get the right weight it must be like

> 00000001Kg

at real time and change itself according to weigh scale weight.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any control characters in the data? I'd assume that's something serial port scales would send between the measurements to be able to handle the data properly.

Comment: no i am not sure but it always giving me continuously receiving string as i show above...the most important thing i have no solution for this

Comment: So maybe you should then check it? We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line of code is just appending everything to the textbox. You might want to clear it beforehand, and maybe try to check if the data you received is your undesired string (`00000001B`) and just don't add it.

To log data, you could use the `TextChanged` event of the textbox... just an idea...

Comment: i did it but its not working to clear the textbox after every receivingdata.